# __FILE__ variable in imported files

Tags: ruby

I have two files in two different directories:

```
module MyModule
  def my_method path
    p File.join (File.dirname __FILE__), path
  end
end
```

and

```
require_relative '../modules/mymodule' # definition of MyModule
class MyClass
  extend MyModule
  my_method 'my_file.yml'
end
```

I am getting output like `my_home_dir/modules/my_file.yml` but I want it to be `my_home_dir/files/my_file.yml` where `files` is the name of the directory where `MyClass` is defined.

I know I can use full path when I call `my_method` but is there a way for imported files to still have `__FILE__` set to the name of the importing file?

Basically in `my_method` I need to have the full path of the file and I want to pass just a path relative to my calling file's path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__FILE__` always is the name of the file containing the `__FILE__` variable, so saying `my_method` will always return where `my_method` is defined, not where `MyClass` calls it.

You can probably get at the information you want using [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller):

```
module MyModule
  def my_method path
    p caller
  end
end

include MyModule # definition of MyModule
class MyClass
  extend MyModule
  my_method 'my_file.yml'
end

my_class = MyClass.new
```

Which outputs:

```
["test.rb:10:in `<class:MyClass>'", "test.rb:8:in `<main>'"]
```

---

Edit:

> the caller array has only file names without paths...

Well, I'd hoped you'd know how to work around that but....

This is in test.rb:

```
require './test2'
class MyClass
  extend MyModule
  my_method __FILE__, 'my_file.yml'
end

my_class = MyClass.new
```

This is in test2.rb:

```
module MyModule
  def my_method path, file
    dir = File.dirname(path)
    p caller.map{ |c| File.join(dir, c) }
  end
end
```

Running test.rb outputs:

```
["./test.rb:4:in `<class:MyClass>'", "./test.rb:2:in `<main>'"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler method available if you can pass in a block; use the block's binding:

```
# In example.rb:
module Example
  def execute_if_main(&block)
    if $PROGRAM_NAME == eval("__FILE__", block.binding)
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the test file:

```
# in test.rb:
require_relative 'example.rb'

include Example

execute_if_main do
  puts "hi, I'm being loaded"
end
```

This will execute the block only if test.rb is being loaded directly by the Ruby interpreter.
If test.rb is loaded instead via some other file via require, the block at the end won't
be executed (which is the idea)

Comment: This answer rules. I've seen the previous hack a few times, which feels like writing Perl in Ruby. Your answer is Ruby in Ruby. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.7 adds Module#const_source_location

```
const_source_location(:MyMoudule)
```